# How do you copy java code from a java file from eclipse without messing up the format?

Tags: java, eclipse, format

I have been trying to copy code from my eclipse program so I can email it to someone that I'm working with, but the format is messed up. This is what I want it to look like:

```
while (insOrDel) {// Asks the user for five different options:
            // add a username or bot
            // add a special username or bot
            // remove a username or bot
            // remove a special username or bot.
            // list all special usernames or bots.
            // list all usernames or bots
            // run weblog sifter.
```

However, it ends up like this when it comes out of the email:

```
        while (insOrDel) {// Asks the user for five different options:
// add a username or bot
// add a special username or bot
// remove a username or bot
// remove a special username or bot.
// list all special usernames or bots.
// list all usernames or bots
// run weblog sifter.
```

Keep in mind this is after Ctrl+Shift+F, and for some reason, the comments aren't indented. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not send the java file as an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when source file uses Tab characters and the destination app you pasting your code in has a different tabwidth.

To avoid this you can set in Eclipse ***/ Window / Preferences / General / Editors / Text Editors*** the option **'Insert spaces for tabs'**